# Is there a version of OSCAR available for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, cluster, beowulf

I'm planning on creating my first Beowulf cluster computer, both my PCs are running standard Ubuntu 16.04, I have heard that you can create clusters using OSCAR, but on their website they only say that they have managed to get OSCAR to work on 14.04 and below back in 2015 (which is the last time they posted an update) so can I either get that version to work on 16.04 or is there a version for 16.04 somewhere? If there is no way to get OSCAR to work I'm open to alternatives. (Perhaps I could run a VM of 14.04 on both machines? but that would unnecessarily suck resources from both)

Comment: This may help: http://oscarmanual.org/15/developers/installation/ubuntu1604

Comment: @andrew.46 I was looking at that, but it looks like it's a different thing? Because it mentions stuff about how it can be used for some kind of medical purposes?  and some of the stuff is labeled "oscar-emr" (emr according to google stands for "electronic medical record") so I think it may be something else.